# Cannot Convert System.String to System.Uri

Tags: c#, flickr

I am using the Web Client Class to download files from the internet (Flickr actually).
This works fine as long as I use : `WebClient().DownloadData(string)`  , however this locks up the UI as it is Not asynchronous.

However when I try `WebClient().DownloadDatAsync(string)`, I get a compile error:
"Unable to convert System.String to System.Uri".

The string MediumUrl returns  `"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/2232/2232/someimage.jpg"`

So the question is how do I convert the string `"http://farm4.static.flickr.com/2232/2232/someimage.jpg"` to a Uri.

Things I have tried-

1. I have tried to cast it to Uri but that does not work either.
2. I have tried `Uri myuri = new uri(string)` - errors out as above.

   ```
   foreach (Photo photo in allphotos)  
   {  
       //Console.WriteLine(String.Format("photo title is :{0}", photo.Title));
       objimage = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(photo.MediumUrl));
       images.Add(new Pictures(new Bitmap(objimage), photo.MediumUrl, photo.Title));  
   }
   ```

Comment: which version of the .NET framework are you using? Is it Compact Framework?

Comment: @Dave Rook: To indent code in a list, you need to indent each line by 8 spaces. It's a Markdown quirk. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3792/how-to-nest-code-within-a-list-using-markdown

Comment: @Dave Rook: You edited this post and raised it to our attention a couple of weeks ago (which was how I was able to ping you). A bit of a delay there but I thought I'd let you know regardless.

Answer (score 44):

This works just fine;

```
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://farm4.static.flickr.com/2232/2232/someimage.jpg");
```

By the way; I notice you mistyped the expression new uri(..., with lowercase uri. This is not your problem, is it? Because it should be "new Uri".

Comment: No there are no typos in my code just in the typing here.
Also the URl is dynamically generated at runtime.

Answer (score 8):

Okay, so I think if the others have proved your URI is valid in their code and it compiles etc. and you also mention it is generated at runtime - it could be that the UriString you are generating at runtime is invalid and not what you are expecting?

Instead of letting an exception be thrown for attempting to create a Uri from an invalid string, I would suggest the following method **IsWellFormedUriString** on the **Uri** class.

```
string uriString = "your_UriString_here";

if (Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(uriString, UriKind.Absolute))
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);
}
else
{
    Logger.WriteEvent("invalid uriString: " + uriString);
}
```

Might help with your debugging also.

Answer (score 5):

```
objimage = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(new Uri(photo.MediumUrl)));
```

> b) I have tried Uri myuri = new uri(string) - errors out as above.

This is the usual way to create a Uri from a string... I don't see why it wouldn't work if the string is a valid URI

Comment: Thanks.
Tried that too ( sorry did not mention above) - no dice. Compile error.

Comment: Thie error could be due to the typo in things I have tried (b). We just can't tell.

Answer (score 5):

```
var yourUri = new UriBuilder(yourString).Uri;
```

So your example would be:

```
wc.DownloadDataAsync(new UriBuilder(photo.MediumUrl).Uri);
objimage = new MemoryStream(wc.Result);
```

You may need to put a check in to see the operation has completed.

Hope that helps,

Dan

Comment: Sorry Does'nt work; Now the error is as follows:
Cannot resolve constructor: Memory Stream(void) candidates are:
MemoryStream (byte[]) (in class memory stream)
memoryStream (int) (in class memory stream)

Comment: public void DownloadDataAsync(System.Uri address)
Member of System.Net.WebClient
Summary:
Downloads the specified resource as a System.Byte array. This method does not block the calling thread.
Parameters:
address: A System.Uri containing the URI to download.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, then

```
wc.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri(photo.MediumUrl));
```

should work.

Comment: Yes, I want to use the Async method but I cannot because of the string to Uri thingy. The method above works fine.