# Parsing URL string into protocol string, server string, and domain string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I'm still relatively new to C# programming and I'm having trouble parsing a URL string.  I would like to take a URL like http://server.example.org and split it into separate strings like protocol, server, and domain name.  Here is what my code looks like so far:

```
string url = "http://server.example.org";
string protocol = url.Substring(0, url.IndexOf(":")); // parse from beginning to colon to get protocol
string server = url.Substring(url.IndexOf("//") + 2, url.IndexOf(".")); // parse from // + 2 to first . for server
string domain = url.Substring(url.IndexOf(".") + 1); // the rest of the string should be the domain
```

The protocol string correctly shows *http* and domain correctly shows *example.org*, but the server string comes out as *server.exampl* instead of *server* as expected.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Convert it to a `Uri`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1465728/8967612) and then you can access all the parts you want via [`Uri.Scheme`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.scheme), `.Host`, `.Segments`, and `.Fragment` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=netcore-3.1) constructor is capable of parsing a *URI*. It has a wealth of properties that give you various attributes. However, if you want to split the *Host* you will need to do it manually

```
var uri = new Uri("http://server.example.org");
var split = uri.Host.Split('.');

Console.WriteLine(uri.Scheme);
Console.WriteLine(uri.Host);
Console.WriteLine(split[0]);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(".",split.Skip(1)));
```

**Output**

```
http
server.example.org
server
example.org
```